# What is $variable[count($variable)-1] Doing?

Tags: php, count

It's a simple question, but no matter where I look, I can't seem to figure out how it works. I believe it's taking the first character off the beginning of $variable, but how does `count($variable)-1` do this?

```
$variable[count($variable)-1]
```

Full code:

```
$fileType  = explode('.',$_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
$fileName = str_ireplace('.jpg', '', $_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
$targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $fileName .'.'.$fileType[count($fileType)-1];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`count($variable)` returns the number of elements in an array, but array indices in PHP are zero-based: that is, a 10 element array has elements with indices 0-9.

So, `$variable[count($variable) - 1]` gets the last element in the array.

Although, this could've been done with [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php): `end($variable) == $variable[count($variable-1)]`.

Comment: Ahh yes. It seems to obvious now. I forgot the variable name was carried from the exploded array. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$fileType is an array, split on the period character, from a string corresponding to a file name.  The `count()` bit gives you the number of elements in the array.  It's returning the last element from the zero-based array, which is the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

$variable is an array. The [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function in PHP counts the number of elements in the array. 
In PHP and other programming languages, the first element index is zero and the last element index is N - 1 for an array of N size.

So  **$variable[count($variable)-1]** will return the last value of the array.